# Extension host terminated unexpectedly with error code 3221225477 Signal: null

Tags: npm, windows-10, visual-studio-code

```
PS D:\> install npm
install : The term 'install' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ install npm
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (install:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When trying to install npm in vscode version VSCodeSetup-x64-1.17.2 in windows 10 OS, I am getting the error.

Error Code from debugger is as below

```
3221225477  Signal:  null
e._onExtensionHostCrashed @ /C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:29
/C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28 Extension host terminated unexpectedly.
e.doShow @ /C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28

C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28 Extension host terminated unexpectedly.
e.doShow @ /C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28
```

Please advise how to resolve this error.

Thanks and Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

You're typing  'install npm install' but the first 'install' is not a binary for the CMD.

Try to install node (which includes npm):

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

Goto the environment path settings, at the "Path" in both user path and system path, there is a more ";" for visual studio code, remove the ";" and restart the VS code, everything is ok now.

I think it's a Microsoft bug.